# What's wrong with this code? I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at DbConnection.main(DbConnection.java:18)

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class DbConnection {


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("TESTING DB");
        Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
            // Move to the end of the result set
            resultSet.last();
            System.out.println("TESTING DB");

    } 

    Driver drv;
    public static Connection dbConnection = null;

    public void databaseCon() throws Exception {
        String strProdDriver = "com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver";
        String strProdServer = "production".equals(System.getProperty("server.env", "deveopment")) ? "jdbc:JSQLConnect://testdb/devtest" : "jdbc:JSQLConnect://testdb/devtest";

        System.out.println("testing");
        try {

            drv = (Driver) Class.forName(strProdDriver).newInstance();
            System.out.println("Driver" + drv);
            DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);
            // dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strProdServer.trim(), "prodholdusr", "ph123");
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strProdServer.trim(), "test", "test");

            System.out.println("Ending ReadConfig Thread");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getDBconnection() {
        return dbConnection;
    }



}
```

Comment: If you're going to reference line numbers in your question, at least be nice enough to mark them in your code.

Comment: you should call databaseCon before using dbConnection

Answer (score 3):

`Main` method never calls `databaseCon()` method, so `dbConnection` is still null when you try to `dbConnection.createStatement();`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling databaseCon() to get the connection in your main method.

It's better to place the databaseCon() in separate class and call that method wherever class you required connection.

And one more thing.close the resources.Once you finished your work with them.